# Combining Entities into ViewModels and using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Most tutorials don't really cover this at all. They just say link your entity to a controller and you're done.

In my business model I have Customers and I have Customer Contacts 1 Customer to >1 Customer Contacts. How do I create a view model for these that will allow them to be edited/created/whatever from the same view?

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.CustomerContacts = new List<CustomerContact>();
        this.Systems = new List<System>();
        this.CreatedByCustomerTickets = new List<Ticket>();
        this.CustomerTickets = new List<Ticket>();
    }

    public long CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> BusinessCustomer { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNotes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerContact> CustomerContacts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<System> Systems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> CreatedByCustomerTickets { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> CustomerTickets { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerContact
{
    public long CustomerContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Zip { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool PromotionalEmails { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: interesting question. I don't find myself using 1 model for all cruds. They all have different Models. Even before getting into issues like lazy loading vs eager and select lists for drop-downs... something as simple as a phone (i often split into 3 fields for creation and editing, then recombine.

Comment: @DaveA Sorry I'm not understanding. Those are actually in their own model and CS file if that's what you mean.

Comment: Definitely a disconnect, but you may have a tight requirement. Please explain why you want to perform Create, Read and Update from the same view

Comment: It just seems appropriate. A customer only has 2 pieces of data which are mostly useless without some contact information.

Comment: I agree that the data relationship is simple. I shy away from combining functionality in screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'd start with this

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
  public Customer Customer {get; set;}
  public CustomerContact CustomerContact {get; set;}
}
```

and work from there.

If you don't need all the properties from the domain objects, you may consider something more like:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
    {
       public long CustomerID { get; set; }
       public ICollection<CustomerContact> CustomerContacts { get; set; }
    }
```

It's really up to you to construct your view models in a way that will meet the needs of your specific project.

Comment: Could you include how the controller and view might work with this? Entity Framework doesn't work with that.

Comment: This is the one thing I dislike about SO -- the no-reason sniping